# comment with no spaces will destroy my table comment

Tags: post, comments, area

```
$display = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_comment WHERE blogid=$theID ORDER BY comment_id DESC")or die(mysql_error());
            echo "<table border='0' align='center' width='900px' style='margin-bottom:20px;margin-top:-20px;background-color:brown;border-top-left-radius:50px;border-top-right-radius:15px;border-bottom-left-radius:15px;border-bottom-right-radius:50px;'>";
                while($r = mysql_fetch_array($display))
                {
                    echo "<tr>";
                        echo "<td align='left' style='font-size:15px;padding-left:25px;color:PowderBlue'><b style='color:LightGreen'><i>".$r['post_name']."</b></i> said:</td>";
                        echo "<td align='right' style='font-size:15px;padding-right:25px;'><b style='color:Yellow'>".$r['Time']."</b>&nbsp&nbsp;<b style='color:Orange'>".$r['Date']."</td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                    echo "<tr>";
                        echo "<td align='justify' style='color:White;font-size:20px;padding-left:25px;'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;".$r['comment_area']."</td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                    echo "<tr>";
                        echo "<td colspan='2' align='center' style='padding-right:25px;color:Yellow'>_______________________________________________________________________________________________________</td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                }
            echo "</table>";
            echo "</div>";
```

I have this codes for my table comment, but when i try to comment spamming it over the opposite edge of the comment area, without spaces and when i hit the post button, there, some texts in my comment cannot be seen. my table is stretched far out of the original comment table. Someone can help me please?

Comment: stop using `mysql_*` function. they are deprecated. use mysqli or PDO instead.

Comment: sorry, if it bothers, or disturbs you, i'm just a beginner in PHP and just doing this for project.

Comment: can you supply a screenshot ? also, posting the rendered HTML in jsfiddle may help.

Comment: i can't post images, because my reputation is below 10 .. >.<

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS to fix this problem.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="test">Thisisverylonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglongspamcomment</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.test {
    word-wrap: break-word;
    overflow: hidden;
    width:250px;}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/NkLuW/